# Prisma (ORM) - get the index value of inserted row

Tags: mysql, database, orm, prisma

I'm trying to use Prisma (ORM) to manage my MySQL database.

When I used MySQL directly I could run `mysql_insert_id()` after insert command to get the `auto_increment` indexes values I've just inserted.

How can I achieve this in Prisma?
The return value of `insert` is the affected rows, not the indexes.

**EDIT**

If you use the `prisma.create()` it does return the object with it's new id.

But if you use `prisma.createMany()` it return only the count of affected rows ?!?!

Someone care to explain the design behind this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to execute the insert statement which returns indexes values.

From the documentation:

> Use `$queryRaw` to return actual records.

> Use `$executeRaw` to return a count of affected rows

So you would need to use the queryRaw method.

Comment: Should I just decide the id myself with `GUI`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
const now = new Date();
const createdRecord = await this.prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title: input.title!,
        content: input.content!,
        created_at: now,
        updated_at: now
      }
    })

// now you can access id of created record by createdRecord.id
const id = createdRecord.id
// ...whatever you want with id
```

Comment: I have edited the question and pointed out that for a single insert I indeed have the id. But for multiple inserts only the number of affected rows is returned